# Java Regexp pattern check

Tags: java, regex

Pattern

```
^\\d{1}-\\d{10}|\\d{1,9}|^TWC([0-9){12})$
```

should validate any of these
1-23232445
1-232323
1-009121212
12
12222
TWC12222
TWC1222324

When i test for TWC pattern doesn't match, I have added "|" to consider OR condition and then to have numbers from 0-9 but limiting to 12 digits. What am i missing ?

Comment: You can always test your regexes here: http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
TWC([0-9)
```

I think this is where it might be not working??

You need

```
TWC([0-9]{12})
```

**Complete answer...**

```
(\d{1}-\d{1,12})|^TWC(\d{1,12})$
```

**even nicer answer ..**

```
^(\\d-|TWC|)(\\d{1,12})$ // this syntax i believe will match your needs.
```

tested :)

```
^([0-9]-|TWC|)([0-9]{1,12})$ // or

^(\d-|TWC|)(\d{1,12})$
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

**breakdown**

```
^
```

this denotes the start of the string

```
\d or [0-9]
```

denotes one character of the numbers 0 through 9 (note \d might not work in some lanagues or require different syntax!)

```
|
```

is essentially an OR

```
{1,12}
```

will only accept a particular pattern 1-12 times for instance in my code the patternw ould be \d or [0-9]

```
$
```

is the end of the line

this essentially checks if the line contains a [0-9] with a - after,TWC, or just a nothing space to account for nothing being there at the start then reads up to 12 digits. Should work for all your cases.

**testing**

[edit code.](http://www.debuggex.com/r/elkDCNeNDy7cybFu)

all unit tests. click on "java" if you want to see them :0

[more testing.](http://www.regexplanet.com/cookbook/ahJzfnJlZ2V4cGxhbmV0LWhyZHNyDwsSBlJlY2lwZRiazbQBDA/index.html)

NOTE:

YOU NEED TO LOOK AT THE SYNTAX OF WHAT YOU ARE USING IN SOME CASES YOU MIGHT NEED TO \ SOME THINGS IN ORDER FOR THEM TO WORK.. IN C++/C its 2 // IN ORDER FOR THESE TO WORK PLEASE BE VERY WARY ABOUT PARTICULAR SYNTAXES.

Comment: This won't currently match strings like `"12"`.

Comment: @progenhard : it does fail for 1-XXX, even for TWC

Comment: @Mad-D `^(\\d-|TWC|)(\\d{1,12})$` did you use this one Mad-D there is different syntax in my answer then the one you are probably using.

Comment: @progenhard: why not this "^\\d{1}-\\d{10}|\\d{1,9}|(^(INC)\\d{1,9})$"

Comment: @Mad-D Well.. you don't have capture groups around the first sections of between the (or's) and also I'm a tad bit confused about what ^INC does. Essentially if you want to capture something you need to have capture groups or they will just cut them out. I tried messing around with your implementation to make it work because it didn't before `^(\d{1}-)$|^(\d{1,9})$|(^(INC)\d{1,9})$` :/ I don't know though the INC thing seems wrong wont work for the TWC cases. There are many different ways you can work with regex for the same pattern. I believe mine is the best way though. Less code and works.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for all the confusion, and also for lying a whole bunch apparently. The issue you're having is that you are using exact quantifiers in a couple of places you don't mean to, namely the `{10}` and `{12}`. This requires *exactly* ten or twelve digits in those spots. What you presumably want is for those to be `{1,10}` and `{1,12}` respectively.

What I would do is something like this, using parentheses and quantifiers to clean everything up and repeating yourself as little as possible, to avoid confusion. You've got three possible prefixes (a digit and a dash, or "TWC", or nothing). I'd put those possibilities all together, and then add the rest. This makes the regex much easier to look at.

```
^(\\d-|TWC){0,1}\\d{1,12}$
```

The breakdown:

`^` is at the beginning, always.

`(\\d-|TWC){0,1}` Next comes either a single digit followed by a dash, or the string `"TWC"`. This prefix occurs either zero times (for no prefix) or one time.

`\\d{1,12}$` Finally, there is a string of one to twelve digits, followed by the end of the line/input (depending on your DOTALL settings of course).

Of course you won't be able to simplify it quite this much if the different prefixes can only allow certain numbers of digits, but this is the basic idea.

---

You've also got what looks like a typo; `TWC([0-9){12})` should be `TWC([0-9]{12})`. I'm guessing this was just a typo when writing out the question though, since what you have right now would blow up at runtime when you tried to use it otherwise, and it sounds like it's working for some of your inputs.

Comment: Are you sure this is right?  I just tried using the original pattern (with the `]` typo fix) with the string "232323", and it matched.  I think it matched the `\\d{1,9}` part.  It doesn't look to me that the regex requires the source to begin with digit+hyphen.

Comment: In fact, your suggested regex matches `"1-"` but does not match `"1-232323"` (using `matches`).

Comment: @ajb I can't replicate either of those results, but maybe I'm the crazy one... I'll edit the answer to be (I hope) foolproof.

Comment: @ajb: thanks for pointing out, solution is not exactly "solving" my problem yet :)

Comment: @ajb Confound it! I was completely wrong about how operator precedence works in Java. The answer has been updated to be clearer and hopefully less wrong.

Comment: @Mad-D I've updated my answer to be less wrong. I believe it should match all your inputs correctly now.

Comment: You could replace the "{0,1}" in "(\\d-|TWC){0,1}" with a "?". Makes it a little neater.

Comment: @TomMcIntyre Yes indeed. I generally prefer to use explicit quantifiers for SO answers, though.